# jQuery Offset returns negative value

Tags: jquery, offset

**am having a scenario like this below**:

In my ui, I will have a textbox. If I have enter a number in the textbox,I need to scroll down to the respective page number.

In `Dom`, I will have some divs with the respective id's. If user entered a page number as 5. I will check for 5th div offset in dom and get top value. By using scrollTop It will scrolled to the 5th div.

Here, Issue is after scrolled down to the 5th div. If again, entered a page number as 2. offset  top value in negative. Hence,ScrollTop defaultly moved to top.

[**Here is fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/balajin/Ldfmvwr9/)

To reproduce this exactly,Go to page number 7 and again go to page number 3 or 4.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be negative? When overflow scroll set on container and you are at bottom the top elements are very negative. You are getting that value before the content moves back up

Comment: Using `position()` helps too as you have about 80px of controls above container

Comment: You are printing the offset value relative to the current position you are at when you hit enter.  Therefore if page X is not in the visible area (is scrolled past), it will print a negative number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldfmvwr9/3/

Try it

```
topValue=$('#container').scrollTop() + $("#"+parseInt(userPageNum)).offset().top - $("#"+parseInt(userPageNum)).height() / 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. You saved my time :)

Answer (score 11):

Late answer, in case it will help someone:

Just use dom offsetTop property. That will be a correct position despite whatever scrolling has happened before.

```
$( something )[0].offsetTop;
```

Comment: Element.offsetTop returns the position relative to its offsetParent (basically any parentElement that is positioned) not the body. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop