# jQuery - ScrollTop()

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using scrollTop() like this :

```
$(window).scrollTop($("header").offset().top);
```

But it does nothing. The `header.offset().top` equals `-962`

I've tested in edge, mozilla and chrome and it's just not working, it does nothing and I've nothing in my console.

Help!

**Edit 1**

alert(window.scrollY); = 0

Comment: `scrollTop` can only go to a minimum value of `0` - which is the top of the page. Anything less than that will just scroll back to the top. If your page is already at the top, then nothing will appear to happen. You need to determine why `offset().top` is returning `-962`

Comment: Can you supply a fiddle with the problem replicated?

Comment: Is there any error in console tab? Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Try using basic DOM property: $(window).scrollTop($('header')[0].offsetTop) . Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632300/jquery-offset-returns-negative-value ; maybe the accepted answer can help you as well.

Comment: Even if I write `$(window).scrollTop(0);`, it does nothing.

Comment: I've edited for more information

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

It's because my `html` and `body` have an `height: 100%`. I've removed this and it is now working.

Thanks !